# Continuity of function and its value.

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

Here's a problem I'm struggling with. Not really sure how to do this. My tools are epsilon delta proofs for continuity and that's about it.

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ be a function which is continuous at the points $x=0$ and $x=1$. Moreover $f$ satisfies $f(x^2)=f(x)$ for all $x>0$ and assume $f(0)=0$.
>
> 1. Show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\ge 0$.
> 2. Does the same conclusion hold if we remove the assumption that “$f$ is continuous at $x=1$”. (But assume the continuity at $x=0$, $f(x^2)=f(x)$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $x_0\in(0,1)$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $x_{n+1}=x_n^2$.

- Show that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $0$.
- Infer that $f(x_0)=0$.
- Then infer that $f(1)=0$.
- To handle $x>1$, note that the hypotheses imply that $f(\sqrt x)=f(x)$ for $x>0$.

I’ll leave the second part open for now; you may find yourself getting ideas for it as you work through the first part.

Comment: @John: You’re very welcome.

Comment: I'm struggling to bring point 1 to point 2, the rest of it rolls pretty well.

Comment: @John: Note $f(x_{n+1})=f(x_n)$ for all $n$.